# Once done using BeautifulSoup4, how do I make soup object further filtered?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn how to parse HTML data so I've chosen this website (http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/ip/Market/Reports/CSMPriceReportServlet) which has real time data for electricity prices.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import pandas as pd

    url = "http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/ip/Market/Reports/CSMPriceReportServlet"
    page = urlopen(url)
    html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


    print(soup.get_text())
```

My question is how do I further parse / filter a BS4 object once it's created?

I just want the data that updates so I can throw it into a pandas dataframe.

Like so:

### Date (HE)| Time |Price ($)| Volume (MW)

### 01/15/2021| 14 |13:10 |40.16| 80

### 01/15/2021| 14 |13:05 |40.18| 100

### 01/15/2021 | 14 |13:00| 40.16| 80

Comment: depending on the format of the page, you can try pandas.read_html(), or if that doesn't work well on that site, you can use beautifulsoup.find/find_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As goalie1998 mentioned the esiest way is to use `pandas`, just two lines of code.

**Example**

Notice, pandas `read_html()` stores all tables in a list of data frames. Cause the table you want is the third in the source you could select it directly by slicing data frame list with `[2]`

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/ip/Market/Reports/CSMPriceReportServlet')[2]
```

**Output**

```
    Date (HE)   Time    Price ($)   Volume (MW)
0   01/15/2021 14   13:10   40.16   80
1   01/15/2021 14   13:05   40.18   100
2   01/15/2021 14   13:00   40.16   80
3   01/15/2021 13   12:40   40.16   80
4   01/15/2021 13   12:00   40.01   100
5   01/15/2021 12   11:54   40.01   100
6   01/15/2021 12   11:00   40.18   100
7   01/15/2021 11   10:54   40.18   100
8   01/15/2021 11   10:24   40.16   80
9   01/15/2021 11   10:00   40.18   100
```

---

### Just in case you really have to go with `beautifulsoup`

1. Select the third `table` or `table`without a class on the site
2. Select all the `tr` in the `table`and loop over them and append all texts from the `td`s in the data list
3. Import the data lists in to `pandas`

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

url = "http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/ip/Market/Reports/CSMPriceReportServlet"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

data = []
rows = soup.select('table:not([class]) tr')
for i,row in enumerate(rows):
    if i == 0:
        cols = row.find_all('th')
    else:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
    
pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```